# Javascript or CSS sprite sheet animation timing adjustment for each frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

[image]

Im working on a sprite sheet animation. I'm trying to adjust a timing for a each frame, for example, a second sprite stays longer than the others of this image.

I've seen a few sprite sheet animation tutorial on Youtube but I found they translate entire sprite sheet image without any timing adjustment. Thank you in advance.

just following a tutorial..